# How can I see css changes without restarting xamarin app

Tags: c#, android, css, xamarin, webview

I'm building a xamarin app where I'm using a Preprocessed Razor Template as a webview. I used this guide to set it up: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/

It's working great and all but every time I do some css changes I have to restart the app to see the css changes. Is there another way to do this so I don't have to restart the app every time?

I tried adding a button which reloads the webView but that did not work. This is my activity:

```
public class ItemWebViewActivity : Activity
{
    WebView webView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var itemId = Intent.GetIntExtra("itemId", 0);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ItemWebView);
        webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

        var dataService = new AzureDataService();
        var item = dataService.GetItem(itemId);

        Button refreshButton = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.refreshButton);

        refreshButton.Click += ReloadPage;

        var decodedDesc = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Description);

        var vm = new Item()
        {
            Artist = item.Artist,
            Title = item.Title,
            Picture = item.Picture,
            Description = decodedDesc
        };

        var template = new ItemWebView() { Model = vm };
        var page = template.GenerateString();

        webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",page, "text/html", "charset=UTF-8",null);

    }

    private void ReloadPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView.Reload();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Are you try  load data again?

Comment: Your css files are packaged with the apk, which has to be deployed to the device after changes. Don't see any chance there.